# Cannot position div at bottom of its containing div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this using the below code. Any ideas about what I could be doing wrong. It works in dreamweaver(thought not even in live view) but sticks to the top and left in Safari and Firefox.

I have also tried to replace the masthead div into a table containing a tr/ td with vertical-align:bottom w/ no luck...  I foremost hope to learn how to position the inner(absolutely positioned) div at the bottom of the outer(relatively positioned) div.

The (present) site, using hotspots, can be seen at http://jjayladslair.com to get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I'd like to position the 3 objects 15% form the bottom and 45% form the left of its container instead of using dreamweaver's awful hotspots on top of a flattened masthead (single) image. (This question has been asked before, but no solutions work so I've opened a newer thread.)

**CSS:**

```
#3_objects_finally {
    left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 286px;
    bottom: 15%;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

#masthead_test {
    height: 132px;
    width: 1021px;
    background-image: url(images/new_masthead.gif);
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="masthead_test">
    <div id="3_objects_finally">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/websites_button_new.gif" width="286" height="31" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/mobile_button_new.gif" width="286" height="31" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/SEO_new_button.gif" width="286" height="31" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The key issue here, the CSS for "3_objects_finally" is missing in your question. Is there any?

Answer (score 2):

ID and class names cannot start with a number.

That's why your styles for #3_objects_finally aren't working.